# Spring Cloud Feign issue with version 2020.04 with MultiValueMap

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

Below is the endpoint which I am to calling.

```
@PostMapping(value = "test",
      consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
  Response addVariable(MultiValueMap<String, Object> body);
```

It was working fine with previous versions of SpringFeign **Hoxton.SR1**.
With current version I am getting 500 error from service provider. There is no change from the service provider and still works fine with previous version.

```
> <html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
> content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/> <title>Error 500 Request
> failed.</title> </head> <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500 Request failed.</h2>
> <table> <tr><th>URI:</th><td>/test</td></tr>
> <tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>500</td></tr> <tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Request
> failed.</td></tr>
> <tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.rest.CamundaJerseyResourceConfig</td></tr>
> </table> </body> </html> workflow-services
> a1d051de-f70e-4248-900c-2c5c2d6d5cc0 W586159 - 2021.11.13 15:52:06.835
> [http-nio-7071-exec-2] <--- END HTTP (522-byte body)
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

No code change..Only version upgrade from **2.2.4.RELEASE** --> **2.5.6**

Code is breaking because of the addional change which was added in the new version of spring encoder.

```
if (Objects.equals(requestContentType, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)) {
                this.springFormEncoder.encode(requestBody, bodyType, request);
                return;
            }
```

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: Yes. But a different approach.

Comment: Do you have any fix?

Comment: I ended up using feign.form.FormData ```@RequestPart(name = "file") FormData file```